# Gatsby image path from json

Tags: json, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, gatsby

**Edit: Got it working** even if it feels kinda wrong this way.. Any ideas to make it possible to only use the filename and not a relative path would be appreciated. Anyway, here is how I got it working:

data.json

```
[
        {
          "slug": "bloom",
          "name": "Bloom",
          "image": {
            "src": "../images/socks1.jpg"
          }
        }
]
```

Query:

```
{
  allDataJson {
    edges {
      node {
        slug
        name
        image {
          src {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                src
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

---

I am trying to display an image of which the name is stored in data.json and the file itself is in src/images

src/data/data.json

```
[
        {
          "slug": "sock1",
          "name": "sock1",
          "image": "socks1.jpg"
        }
]
```

If instead of the pure filename, I provide a url to any image on the web it works.. Tried getting it to work as follows:

gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
          options: {
            name: `data`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
          },
        },
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
          options: {
            name: `images`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
          },
        },
        `gatsby-transformer-json`,
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      ],
    }
```

product.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import get from 'lodash/get'

class ProductPage extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const products = get(this, 'props.data.allDataJson.edges')
    console.log(products)

    return (
      <Layout>
        {products.map(({ node }) => {
          return (
            <div key={node.name}>
              <p>{node.name}</p>
              <img src={node.image} />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductPage


export const productsQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allDataJson {
      edges {
        node {
          slug
          name
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

All that's being outputted on the frontend is

```
<img src="socks1.jpg">
```

If I query for all files in the GraphiQl I get them, but (not sure about this one) I think the image field is just not recognized as file type field (cant query for src etc)

Any pointers would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query should similar to this:

```
export const productsQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allDataJson {
      edges {
        node {
          slug
          name
          image{
            publicURL
            childImageSharp{
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Then you can output the path like this:

```html
<img src={node.image.childImageSharp.fluid.src} />
```

You don't have to use fluid, you use other [types of responsive images](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#two-types-of-responsive-images)

Comment: He asked how to use replace the absolute path with relative path in the JSON file.